# How to update my dashboard using slicer from my table

Tags: excel, replication, dashboard, slicers, excel-tables

Ok, I have one tab that I collect data from Power BI reports. In this tab (Export FF) I created a table called "FFLExport", I also have another tab called "Dashboard" where I created  13 slicer base on the table "FFL", once I manipulate the filter in the slicer from the dashboard tab I have the final results in the Export FF tab, and I want to replicate this filter lines in my dashboard tab, because is not all the columns that I need form the "FFLExport" tab.
I am running out of option and time. does anyone can help me on this task?

I have try query but don't update automatically once I play around with the slicer's filter.